# DLM package, state equation, maximum likelihood with constant terms

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, dlm

My question is about the DLM package and the dlmMLE.

Lest's say that I have a bivariate model of this kind:

$$Y(t)= Fb(t)+e(t)$$
$$b(t) = u + Gb(t) +w(t)$$

$$b(t)=(b_1(t),b_2(t)),\quad u = (u_1,u_2)$$
Rewriting the model in matrix notation, the state equation becomes:
$$d(t) = H d(t) +w(t),$$
where $d(t)= (b(t),1,1)$  and $H$ is a matrix 4x4 given by  the merging the 2 matrices 2x4 $[G,\text{diag}(u)]$ and $ [0,\text{diag}(1,p)]$, and the variance of the innovations $w$ is a matrix of zeros except for the upper right 2x2. Morover I assume that $C_0=\text{diag}(1e3,1e3,0,0)$

Since it doesn't work well I was wondering if it is the right way to write it?

Thanks I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: In another way my question is how can I estimate through the dlm package an arima(1) with intercept different from zero?

Answer (score 2):

You might subtract the constant terms from the observed $Y$'s and maximize the likelihood with respect to all parameters in the state space model plus the constant terms.

Or, you might turn to packages like [FKF](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FKF/index.html) which explicitly allow for intercepts in both the state and measurement equation.

Comment: Thanks, I would prefer not to subtract the constant terms cause I would like to estimate them.

Comment: The two things are not incompatible; what you subtract is a value that is also optimized along with the rest of parameters.

Comment: @F.Tusell : Dear Mr. Tusell, I hope I am not acting against the etiquette of CV, but I have a very similar problem which I posted here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155569/state-space-model-with-intercept-in-transition-equation-fkf-r . Could you maybe explain this substracting method? I followed your advice to use the FKF package but it seems much more complicated to me than dlm.

Comment: Answered privately. Either I misread the original question, or it may have changed along the way: my suggestion of subtracting from $Y(t)$ came on the understanding that the non-random inputs were in the observation equation, NOT on the state equation, so it does not apply here as the equations stand.