# MLE estimation of mean-adjusted state-space model

Tags: r, state-space-models, dlm

I am trying to estimate coefficients of a state-space model described in [Diebold et.al (2006)](https://www.sas.upenn.edu/%7Efdiebold/papers/paper55/DRAfinal.pdf) with data and scripts [here](http://www.estima.com/procs_perl/dra_joe_2006.zip):
$$y_t = Zf_t + \epsilon_t$$
$$f_t-\mu_t = T(f_{t-1}-\mu)+\eta_t$$
The main issue is that I have not been able to specify this model in the `dlm` package for R, as the estimation of the means is more complicated than expected. I have found a [guide for MATLAB](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/using-the-kalman-filter-to-estimate-and-forecast-the-diebold-li-model.html) with a mapping function [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/47479/versions/2/previews/Example_DieboldLi.m/index.html). The guide is quite in-depth and extensive, however the implementation in MATLAB and `dlm` package differ. The two-step VAR(1) approach is the same:

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
require(dlm)

df <- read.delim('dra data.txt')

yield <- as.matrix(df[,c(2:(ncol(df)-3))])
maturities <- c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,30,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120)
lambda0 <- 0.0609

X <- matrix(c(rep(1,length(maturities)), (1-exp(-lambda0*maturities))/(lambda0*maturities), 
              ((1-exp(-lambda0*maturities))/(lambda0*maturities) - exp(-lambda0*maturities))), ncol = 3)

beta <- matrix(rep(0,3*nrow(yield)), ncol = 3)
eps <- matrix(rep(0,length(maturities)*nrow(yield)), ncol = length(maturities))
i <-1
for (i in 1:nrow(yield)) {
  y <- as.data.frame(yield[i,])
  data <- cbind(y,X)
  names(data)<- c("y", "c1","c2","c3")
  reg <- lm(formula = y~c1+c2+c3-1, data = data)
  beta[i,]<- reg$coefficients
  eps[i,] <- reg$residuals
}

colnames(beta)<- c("b0","b1","b2")
library(vars)
VAR(beta,p = 1, type = "const")->varbeta
varbeta$varresult
varlagbeta <- matrix(c(varbeta[["varresult"]][["b0"]][["coefficients"]][1:3],
                       varbeta[["varresult"]][["b1"]][["coefficients"]][1:3],
                       varbeta[["varresult"]][["b2"]][["coefficients"]][1:3]),byrow = T, ncol = 3)
rownames(varlagbeta)<-c("beta_0","beta_1","beta_2")
colnames(varlagbeta)<-c("beta_0_l1","beta_1_l1","beta_2_l1")

cat('VAR(1) matrix of estimateed coefficients: \n')
print(varlagbeta)
vecG <- as.vector(t(varlagbeta))
cat("VAR(1) covariance matrix of residuals: \n")
print(summary(varbeta)$covres)
```

The one-step state-space model is not so successful. I've rewritten the model as in the tutorial and this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21554/dlm-package-state-equation-maximum-likelihood-with-constant-terms):
$$y_t-Z\mu = Zx_t+e_t$$
$$x_t = Tx_{t-1}+\eta_t$$
Where $x_t = f_{t-1}-\mu$ and tried to implement it in `dlm`:

```
vecG <- as.vector(t(varlagbeta))
matW <- summary(varbeta)$covres
matW <- chol(matW)
vecW <- c(log(matW[1,1]),matW[1,2],matW[1,3],log(matW[2,2]),matW[2,3],log(matW[3,3]))
vecV <- diag(cov(eps))
vecC <- cov(beta)
vecm <- apply(beta,2,mean)

params0 <- c(vecG, vecW, log(vecV), vecm, log(lambda0))
param<- params0
var_rest <- function(x){
  return(exp(x))
}


stl <- ncol(yield)
poz <- nrow(yield)

estpar <- function(param){
  lam <- var_rest(param[length(param)])
  
  F.mat <-matrix(rep(0,3*stl),nr=stl)
  F.mat[,1:3] <- c(rep(1,length(maturities)), (1-exp(-lam*maturities))/(lam*maturities), 
                   ((1-exp(-lam*maturities))/(lam*maturities) - exp(-lam*maturities)))
  
  V <- diag(var_rest(param[16:32]))
  
  G.mat <- matrix(rep(0,3*3),nr=3)
  
  G.mat[1:3, 1:3] <- matrix(param[1:9],nrow =3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
  
  W.mat <-matrix(rep(0,3*3),nrow=3)
  #param[c(28,31,33)] <- var_rest(param[c(28,31,33)])
  param[c(10,13,15)] <- var_rest(param[c(10,13,15)])
  W.mat[1,1] <-param[c(10)]
  W.mat[2,1:2] <-param[c(11,13)]
  W.mat[3,1:3] <-param[c(12,14,15)]
  W <- W.mat%*%t(W.mat)
  
  m0.mat <- rep(0,3)
  C0.mat <- diag(1e6,3)
  
  return( dlm(m0=m0.mat, C0=C0.mat, FF=F.mat, GG=G.mat, W=W,V=V))
}


dlm_optim <- function(y, parm, build, method = "BFGS", ..., debug = FALSE){
  logLik <- function(parm,y, ...) {
    mod <- build(parm, ...)
    y2 <- sweep(y,2,X%*%parm[33:35])
    return(dlmLL(y = y2, mod = mod, debug = debug))
  }
  out <- optim(parm, logLik, y=y, method = method, ...)
  return(out)
}

pok1a <- dlm_optim(as.matrix(yield),params0,build = estpar, hessian=T,control=list(maxit=10000))#, control=list(maxit=5))
```

MMy estimates are completely off. There are 3 main issues:

1. How to specify the `estpar` function so that the means will be estimated as well?
2. What to do with the $m_0$ and $C_0$ parameters? The Matlab example does not specify anything like it, but the `dlm` function requires it as input.
3. If I use `BFGS` optimization method (which the authors used), I have singularity issues with the covariance matrices. If I use `L-BFGS-B`, the results are off.

I know this is a long and complicated question, but any help would be appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at https://dylanb95.github.io/statespacer/articles/selfspec.html

It implements the same model, but using the statespacer package (written by me)

Comment: Hi! I've been using your package and played with this vignette for a couple of hours and figured out how to estimate the simple (yields only) model from Diebold et.al. However, when adding additional macroeconomic variables, the computational complexity becomes huge, with the Hessian matrix being numerically non-invertible. I was wondering about getting in touch with you, in order to figure out where the issue lies. Edit: If you want, I can share a link for my repository with the script used

Comment: Yeah sure, feel free to contact me! In the meantime, maybe you could try to add the argument standard_errors = FALSE (and possibly also diagnostics = FALSE) to the statespacer function call. This would circumvent the computation of the Hessian, although optim itself might still try to calculate it during the optimisation routine though.

Comment: I've found that there is much bigger issue with the extended model they use - the authors incorporate macro-variables as observed state variables! So these variables (capacity utilization, inflation and FFR, using your notation) are in the observation vector $y_t$, as well as in the state vector $\alpha_t$. This I could get around by extending matrix $Z$, however, then the matrix $H$ would not be invertible (as the errors of ! I think I will create a new question with this and share the link in edit.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem that the H matrix isn't invertible, but because of it, you can't use collapse = TRUE. (In order to collapse the observation vector for computational gains, the H matrix should be invertible.) So try to rerun the code, but using collapse = FALSE